# Нужно сделать форму поиска по центру в html

Tags: html, css

```css
.search__box {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f7cb99;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search__box">
  <input type="text" class="search__txt" placeholder="Найти работу">
  <a href="#" class="search__button">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Пытался сделать эту форму поиска по центру страницы через margin, но это получается не правильно и при уменьшении страницы Поиск выглядит ужасно. Центрирование почему-то не работает. Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема в том, что форма поиска не зафиксирована по центру страницы. Она находится левее страницы. Я хочу узнать, как сделать поиск по центру правильным путём.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.search__box {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f7cb99;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search__box">
  <input type="text" class="search__txt" placeholder="Найти работу">
  <a href="#" class="search__button">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```